# How to force all spawner mobs to spawn on one platform?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to make a mob drop trap with spawners in the Nether, and as it's the Nether I can't use water, so I want to have them spawn on one platform which retracts with pistons every so often. I tried to cover the area around the platform with cobblestone slabs, but the mobs were just spawning on the slabs. How do I make sure they spawn **on that platform only** (with the least amount of blocks)?

I recreated the platform with the spawners in a superflat world, the gold blocks represent the platform where the mobs should spawn:

[image: the platform and spawners seen from above]

Comment: Is it possible for you to include a picture so that we can get a better image of what you mean?

Comment: @Riftcaster added it. Not the original spawners as those have too many failed attempts in them to serve as a proper image, but a similar spawner platform

Comment: Have you thought of using torches or lava, lol?

Comment: @Riftcaster For some reason, lighting the place didn't work. Filling the are with blocks, like Rudolf answered, did work though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prevent Blazes spawning around the platform, you can do a few things:

- Fill the area around with blocks, or
- Fill the ground and adjacent walls with torches. Place them everywhere, on each block you can, except the platform and it's close surroundings

I'd recommend doing something in between - encasing the spawner and platform, and fill the area outside of the box with torches.

Good luck!